# Bandwidth Control with Queue in Mikrotik

Tags: networking, bandwidth, mikrotik, queue-management

good time
I set a bandwidth limit in Mikrotik(simple queues) for each IP, and now I need to set a general bandwidth limit for each of my networks.
My question is how to set a 10M limit for a range like 192.168.102.0/24 and a 3M limit for each user on this network like 192.168.102.1 and 192.168.102.2 and etc. So that even if all network users start downloading, they will not be able to download more than their own network ceiling of 10M?
In other words, suppose like next picture:
[image: Example]

I set 10M bandwidth for a group of users and now I want to consider 3M bandwidth for per users in this group but the total consumption of this group should not exceed10M

Update: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my main problem. The main problem is not exceeding the total bandwidth of users. Let me explain my question again with the help of mathematics
We have 10 users and we want to give each of them a maximum speed of 3 megabytes. So, normally we need 30 megabytes, but we don't want their total speed to exceed 10 megabytes. The main problem is limiting the total bandwidth of users to 10 megabytes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the text and added an image. I hope my questions are clearer

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this but again found my own post on this. This works for me and I am also using Simple Queue.

[Limit Bandwidth to Per IP MikroTik](https://rizwanranjha.com/networking/mikrotik/limit-bandwidth-to-per-ip-mikrotik)

**Note**: This Tutorial is written with the following scenario

1. **Total Bandwidth**: 70 Mbps - Already limited by the ISP.
2. **Total Users**: 75 end users.
3. **Limit Bandwidth**: 8 Mbps for each IP Address and User cannot exceed by Maximum Download (8 Mbps) / Maximum Upload (8 Mbps) speed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my main problem. The main problem is not exceeding the total bandwidth of users. Let me explain my question again with the help of mathematics
We have 10 users and we want to give each of them a maximum speed of 3 megabytes. So, normally we need 30 megabytes, but we don't want their total speed to exceed 10 megabytes. The main problem is limiting the total bandwidth of users to 10 megabytes

Comment: Hi @s.mostafa.b, In the company, do you have more than 10 Mb ISP connection? If so, you have to either ask ISP or have to split it before your MikroTik redistribute it. Thank You

Comment: Yes, we have more than 10 Mb ISP connection in the company. Thank you for your time